# How to repeat a data list with two vectors in R

Tags: r

I have a list data X with two vectors

```
X[1]=(1,2,3,5,6,9,7,8)
X[2]=(2,3,4,5,6)
```

I want to get a new list data Y

```
Y[1]=(1,2,3,5,6,9,7,8,1,2,3,5,6,9,7,8)-repeat x[1]
Y[2]=(2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6)-repeat x[2]
```

I used Y<-rep(X,2) but get

```
Y[1]:(1,2,3,5,6,9,7,8)
Y[2]:(2,3,4,5,6)
Y[3]:(1,2,3,5,6,9,7,8)
Y[4]:(2,3,4,5,6)
```

How to do it right? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sapply`/`lapply` :

```
sapply(X, rep, 2)

#[[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 5 6 9 7 8 1 2 3 5 6 9 7 8

#[[2]]
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4 5 6
```

**data**

```
X <- list(c(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 7, 8), c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having problems accessing the list elements - use `[[1]]` etc.

```
X  <-  list( c(1,2,3,5,6,9,7,8),
            c(2,3,4,5,6))
Y = list(rep(X[[1]], 2),
         rep(X[[2]], 2))
# R > Y
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 5 6 9 7 8 1 2 3 5 6 9 7 8
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `map` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map(X, rep, 2)
```

#### data

```
X <- list(c(1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 7, 8), c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```